# How to correlate a sample curve with a reference curve

Tags: python, python-3.x, signal-processing

I have a sensor that is continually collecting data (shown in blue) every minute  that outputs a voltage output. I have a reference sensor collecting data (shown in red) that outputs in the units that I am interested. I am interested in determining a scaling factor so that I can scale the blue sensor's data to match the red sensor's data.

Normally, I would do a simple linear regression between the values of two sensors at any given time, which would give me a scaling factor based on the slope of the regression. I have noticed, however, that red sensor is slower at sensing a change in the environment, and can anywhere from 6-15 minutes behind -- this makes a regression difficult because at any given time, the two sensors may be measuring different things.

I was wondering if there is any sort of curve fitting that can be performed such that I can extract a scaling factor so that I can scale the blue sensor's data to match the red sensors.

I typically work in Python, so any Python packages (e.g. Numpy/Scipy) that would help with this would be especially helpful.

[image: curve calibration]

Comment: You can get the lag, and then shift one signal by that lag, then do your linear regression scale computation.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39336727/get-lag-with-cross-correlation

I would also look at scipy signal cross-correlation:
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.1/reference/generated/scipy.signal.correlate.html

Comment: Thanks for the response! I looked into doing this but my problem was that my lag was not consistent over the whole measurement period (e.g. one peak might be 6 mins behind, then the next one might be 10). Do you have any good strategies for reconciling that?

Comment: Can't you use an RBT with a KL divergence measurement to "find the closest" match between both curves? (Your problem should be the same as a 2D Image fusion). So you can formulate a minimization problem and use sk learn or scipy to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help. What I ended up doing was finding all the local maxima and minima on the reference curve, then used those peak locations to search for the same maxima or minima on the sample curve. I basically used the reference curve's maxima/minima points as the center of a "window" and I would search for the highest/lowest point on the sample curve within a few minutes of the center point.

Once I had found all the matched maxima/minima on the sample curve, I then could perform a linear regression between these points to determine a scaling factor.

[image: Sample]

[image: Reference][image: Correlation]