# How to get cross correlation value and lag value in Python?

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, matplotlib, cross-correlation

I was converting code from MATLAB to Python. In MATLAB, the code used for cross-correlation is:

```
[acor,lag]=xcorr(h,k);
```

In Python cross-correlation is done by NumPy:

```
z=np.correlate(h,k)
```

But in `np.correlate` it is returning only correlation value not lag time. How do I get both correlation value and lag value in Python?

I also tried with matplotlib:

```
z=plt.xcorr(h,k)
```

NB: where `h` and `k` are my inputs having the same length.

Comment: Can you post some input/output data of your desired results?  If I understand you correctly, you want to use scipy for this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39336727/get-lag-with-cross-correlation

Comment: I tried with the scipy to find lag and it worked thank you but on comparing the size of z(correlation value ) and lag value, doesn't match.lag showing 82 and length of z showing 119